# How do I get the image sizes of multiple images in react native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Here is the code Snippet

```
 <ScrollView style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: theme.background}]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
        {pages &&
          pages.map((page, index) => {
            const url = `https://link`;
            let imageHeight;
            Image.getSize(url, (width, height) => {
              imageHeight = (height * Dimensions.get('screen').width) / width;
              console.log(imageHeight); // This returns Values
            });
            console.log(imageHeight); // This returns undefined

            return (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: url,
                }}
                // I want use the imageHeight here in styles
                style={[styles.images, {height: 650}]}
                key={index}
              />
            );
          })}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here `pages` is an array of image links... after getting the data I need from the `Image.getSize()` function I'm storing that data in a previously declared variable called `imageHeight` but even after that if I log the `imageHeight` outside the `getSize()` function, it returns `undefined`

Please Help!

Comment: Image.getSize() function will return immediately, the success block will be executed after the image is fetched. this is why you are getting undefined.
Can you tell me what do want to do with height?

Comment: I want to use that imageHeight in the styles and set the Image component's height = imageHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Images.getSize` is asyncronous thats why when you log the `imageHeight` it became undefined because it get excuted before the `imageSize` is fetch.

```
<ScrollView style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: theme.background}]}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={1}
    onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
    {pages &&
      pages.map((page, index) => {
        const url = `https://link`;

        return (
          <ImageLoader
            url={url}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
  </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

ImageLoader component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const ImageLoader = ({ url }) => {
  const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Image.getSize(url, (width, height) => {
      const calculatedHeight = (height * Dimensions.get('screen').width) / width;
      setImageHeight(calculatedHeight);
    });
  }, [url]);

  if (imageHeight === null) {
    // Render a placeholder while the image height is being calculated
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Image
      source={{
        uri: url,
      }}
      style={[styles.images, { height: imageHeight }]}
    />
  );
};

export default ImageLoader;
```

Comment: Hey! It returns the error ```Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.```